# Prevent Proguard from removing empty constructor of fragment

Tags: android, constructor, fragment, proguard

You know, all subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor but when using proguard these constructors will be removed. I have specified below commands but empty constructor still be removed. Can anyone help me to keep empty constructor of Fragment? Thanks you.

```
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment { 
   public <init>(***);
   #public <init>(); //already tried this
}

-keepclassmembers public class * extends com.xxx.MyFragment { 
   public <init>(***);
   #public <init>(); //already tried this
}
```

Answer (score 54):

This should work  :

```
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment { 
   public <init>(...);
```

I believe even this should be enough :

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

as keeping the class will oblige proguard to keep the default constructor.

Comment: I don't use 2nd option because I don't want to keep all Fragment subclasses. With the 1st option, I still didn't see the empty constructor when decompile. Aw, thanks you for your answer.

Comment: You should not worry about seeing the constructor or not. If you just provide a default empty constructor, this can be removed : it will be added by the java compiler. There should be no trouble when the SDK will create your fragment. Did you experience any trouble on runtime ?

Comment: The second setting is sufficient indeed; it will keep all extensions and, automatically, their parameterless constructors (assuming they are present in the original classes).

Comment: I think there will be problem if no empty constructor provided because I experienced this before, application will crash or start with old data (if onSaveInstanceState is not overrided) when fragment recreated. Is there a way to keep empty constructor without keeping the whole fragment?

Comment: My observation with updating from Android Studio 3.5.x to 3.6.1: The new R8 started to purge constructors in full mode, needed to disable that.

Comment: How did you disable it @InI4?